# Vector Grid, Graphical Modeler & Input Extent

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-grid, qgis-modeler, vector-layer

I created my process in QGIS graphic interface with treatments. In my process I need to create a vector grid. This algorithm allows a vector layer to define my extent.

But in the graphical modeler I can't do it, I have to enter an extent like this:

```
-0.793282323236,-0.792284809119,45.2490964215,45.2499104167
```

How can I use a vector layer as extent in the graphical modeler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Extent** parameter and link it to `Grid extent` option in the *Vector grid* tool:

[image: Modeler]

Now when you run the model, you can select to either take the extent from a layer or from the canvas:

[image: Running model]

Comment: @TimothéeColas - Most welcome! Hope it helps :)

Comment: How can do if my layer who define extent is the result of a previous treatment ? I forgot a part of the problem :D

Comment: @TimothéeColas - I think you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) because you may need to create a **custom script** to retrieve the extent for a layer from a previous algorithm. Perhaps you can also add a screenshot of an example model to illustrate what you need as I'm not completely sure :)

Comment: I finally found how to do ! In Specific graphical modeler tools, there is "vector boundary" or something like this (my qgis is in french ;p). So this tool give you : Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax, Extent. Greta isn't it ?

Comment: @TimothéeColas - Don't think I've seen that tool before! Well done :)